# Are Zombies helpful in Objective-C++?

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access, objective-c++

I am debugging an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` in Objective-C++ and like a good SO student I have set an Environment variable of `NSZombieEnabled` to `YES`.

I'm not getting any Zombies, though, just `(gdb)` in the log and then `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on various (C++) lines of my code.

Question: Am I using Zombies wrong, or do they just ignore the C++ parts of my project?

Example:

`if (this->squares[i][j] == 1) //  <-- EXC_BAD_ACCESS on this line. The array exists and shows up in the debugger... and i and j both exist and are 0.`

Stack:

```
Thread 1, Queue : com.apple.main-thread
#0  0x00009309 in Board::draw(float, float, float, float, float) at /Developer/of_007_iphone/apps/cwi007/iTicTacToe/src/gameplay/gameBoard.cpp:53
#1  0x0000a2f1 in SuperBoard::drawBig(float, float, float) ()
#2  0x000044b8 in testApp::draw() ()
#3  0x0020fc16 in ofAppiPhoneWindow::timerLoop() ()
#4  0x00218db9 in -[ofxiPhoneAppDelegate timerLoop] ()
#5  0x00ab1749 in __NSFireTimer ()
#6  0x01f898c3 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
#7  0x01f8ae74 in __CFRunLoopDoTimer ()
#8  0x01ee72c9 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#9  0x01ee6840 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#10 0x01ee6761 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#11 0x027651c4 in GSEventRunModal ()
#12 0x02765289 in GSEventRun ()
#13 0x00d29c93 in UIApplicationMain ()
#14 0x002106e1 in ofAppiPhoneWindow::runAppViaInfiniteLoop(ofBaseApp*) ()
#15 0x002219ae in ofRunApp(ofBaseApp*) ()
#16 0x00002fd6 in main ()
```

Comment: Zombies will only work for objective-c objects and if you overrelease them and then send a message to them. In this case, something else is wrong. Can you show us some relevant code?

Comment: @Pragram Yes! Separate question, though, so I've asked it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387988/class-draw-method-works-when-called-directly-but-crashes-when-called-by-anothe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zombies are very helpful because they will flag in the debugger when you send a message to an object that has been deallocated. They only work with Objective-C code however.

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS`errors are tricky in that at the point they occur, that line of code *might* have nothing to do with the root cause of the error. It *may* offer a clue.

That's because the Objective-C runtime will only deallocated released objects when *all* the objects that reside in a particular chunk of memory have been released and are eligible for deallocation.

See here for a great explanation and instructions on how to track down these pesky errors:

[Lou Franco's Understanding EXC_BAD_ACCESS](http://loufranco.com/blog/files/Understanding-EXC_BAD_ACCESS.html)

Answer (score 0):

I will argue "no", because the way `NSZombieEnabled` is implemented is incompatible with `-fobjc-call-cxx-cdtors`. This means that instance variables with desconstructors do not get correctly deconstructed when the object transitions from "live" to "zombie". In my case (just now), I got a report from someone that my project aborted in `NSZombie` when debugging with that technique, and while looking into the issue I tracked it down to a smart-pointer that was auto-clearing delegates on dependent objects not being deconstructed by the runtime.

http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/226062-instance-variables-not-destructed-if-nszombieenabled.html